# Optional being unwrapped with ? in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I have an instance variable in a class which may not have a value, so it is defined as an optional:

```
var myObject: MyClass?
```

In the `viewDidLoad()` method I am checking whether `myObject` has a value and, if so, using the values. However, Xcode is auto-correcting the code to use `?` to unwrap the optional, rather than a `!`

```
if myObject != nil {
  print(myObject?.propertyOne)
  print(myObject?.propertyTwo)
}
```

I am confused about why this works, as I thought that you needed to use a `!` to unwrap optionals, whereas `?` defines an optional. Making things more confusing is that `!` work as well:

```
if myObject != nil {
  print(myObject!.propertyOne)
  print(myObject!.propertyTwo)
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using the question mark in

```
myObject?.propertyOne
```

is called optional chaining. See [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245)

The value of that expression is the value of `propertyOne` if `myObject` is not `nil` otherwise it's `nil`. (I should add that the type of that expression is `T?` where `T` is the type of `propertyOne`.)

The ! operator is a force unwrap. It'll crash your program if `myObject` is nil.
From the documentation:

> Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

You can also use `let` to safely unwrap your optionals as @Macondo2Seattle pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, I was getting a bit confused about the use of the `?` within the statement and your clarification about Optional Chaining has made things much clearer, combined with @Macondo2Seattle suggestion about using `let` and Optional Binding to safely check and unwrap options.

Answer (score 3):

Testing an optional for `nil` is different from testing it for any other value. I think that is what causes your confusion.

E.g. if you have `myObject: MyClass?`, then you can do

```
if myObject != nil { 
     // Still have to unwrap myObject to use it, cause it's still an optional.
     // But at least you knowat this point that force unwrapping of myObject
     // won't fail at runtime.
}
```

but you can't do

```
if myObject != aNonNilValue { 
}
```

-- you need to unwrap to do the latter.

As regards your code sample, a more modern way to do the same thing using Swift 2 syntax would be this:

```
if let myObject = myObject
{
    // myObject is not an optional in this scope, so no unwrapping needed!
    print(myObject.propertyOne)
    print(myObject.propertyTwo)
}
else
{
   print("oops, myObject is nil!")
}
```

This might look a bit confusing at first. `myObject` on the left side of the assignment is a new variable, which holds the unwrapped value of the original `myObject` It doesn't have to have the same name as the optional it takes the value from. If the original `myObject` is nil, then the `if let` won't execute and the block below it won't run.

Using the `if let` approach above can help avoid runtime errors, as it avoids the potentially dangerous force unwrapping operations.

Comment: "but you can't do `if myObject != aNonNilValue { }`” – you can, so long as the wrapped value is `Equatable`. There are implementations of `==` and `!=` for optionals that contain equatable things.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity -- I didn't know that, interesting! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive reply. I understood the use of Optional Bindings, but didn't consider the use of them in conjunction with Optional Chaining (as suggested by @Michael Welch below). Between your two responses I now have a much better understanding, so thanks again :)